# In xarray, large, on-disk dataset from many small cdfs

Tags: python-xarray

I'm new to xarray and would appreciate some help getting my project started. I would like to create a single, on-disk xarray dataset or dataframe from many (1000s) of gas chromatography - mass spectrometry (gcms) files, one per sample run. My initial purpose is simply plotting overlays of data from arbitrary sets of samples, mass-to-charge (m/z) channels, and retention time windows, and xarray's indexing and lazy-loading seem ideal.

I have the data in the manufacturer's (weird) cdf format, one file per sample, and have converted each to pandas dataframe in a format like

```
            t        14       15       16        17        18       19  \
0       271.0  102144.0  14864.0  43584.0   25816.0   82624.0   9992.0   
1       271.1  102720.0  15608.0  42896.0   25208.0   82432.0  10024.0   
2       271.2  101184.0  14712.0  42256.0   24960.0   81472.0   9960.0   
3       271.3  101824.0  14704.0  41216.0   25744.0   83008.0   9984.0   
4       271.4  102208.0  14152.0  41336.0   25176.0   81536.0  10256.0
```

where t goes up to 2100.0 sec and the columns go up to 500 (so 488 x 18000). I have 1000s of such files, each with a different sample name.

I originally envisioned `xr.concat`'ing them into one huge file. So, following the docs, I've been able to create a Dataset structure from a *single* sample and save it to cdf as follows:

```
ds1 = xr.Dataset({'intensity': (['time', 'mz'], c1[["{}".format(x) for x in range(14, 501)]].values)},
             coords={'mz': range(14, 501),
                     'time': c1['t'].values,
                     'sample':['c1']})
ds1.to_netcdf('test_ds1.nc')


<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:    (mz: 487, smp: 1, time: 18185)
Coordinates:
  * time       (time) float64 271.0 271.1 271.2 271.3 271.4 271.5 271.6 ...
  * mz         (mz) int64 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 ...
  * smp        (smp) <U2 'c1'
Data variables:
    intensity  (time, mz) float64 1.005e+05 1.444e+04 4.162e+04 2.536e+04 ...
```

(note mz represents mass-to-charge-ratio, which is what 15, 16...500 are)

As expected, loading several dsi's with `xr.open_dataset` does not increase memory use of the python process (I'm looking at activity monitor on mac osx), which is good.

However, on running

```
d = xr.concat([ds0, ds1], dim='sample')
```

memory use shoots up ~70MB/sample, indicating that `d` is fully in memory, and this won't scale to the 1000s of samples.

What can I do in xarray to enable fast access to the dataset on disk? It seems like `xr.concat` is not a scalable way to create a huge cdf file. Perhaps I need a way to `xr.concat` directly to disk, or a separate tool to combine cdfs.

Answer (score 1):

Xarray's lazy loading for combining multiple netCDF files on disk requires [using dask](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/dask.html).

I recommend using `open_mfdataset` which takes care of most of these details automatically, e.g., `xr.open_mfdataset('all/my/files/*.nc', concat_dim='sample')`.

Comment: Works for 100 files. On trying 300 files I get `OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files`.

Comment: I thought of combining into bigger chunks after opening this way, e.g.  `ds = xr.open_mfdataset(100 files)` `ds.to_netcdf(bigfile)` but memory usage starts to skyrocket immediately, so it must by trying to load the whole thing into memory before saving the new cdf file.

Comment: The `Too many open files` error is one we know about and are working on. Sometimes you can increase the limit on open files. Unfortunately, the scipy netCDF writer doesn't work out of core, but the other netCDF backends (netcdf4-python and h5netcdf) will.